# Duplicate entries in contents

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I found a lot of questions with the same problem.But mine is a little different.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\pagebreak 
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{SEQUENCES AND SERIES}
\section{Sequences and Their Limits}
\section{Limit Theorems}
\input{file name}
\end{document}
```

The 3rd section is in the file I inserted and it appears as two sections in the table of contents.
[image]

What is the cause of this?

Does it have anything to do with the 3rd section being in an inserted file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Without seeing what's inside your input file, it's hard to tell. Do you simply have a duplicate section in that file? `\input` just behaves as if the code in that file was directly in your main document.

Comment: That file simply  has the last part of section 2 and the section 3.It was pretty large.That's why I didn't include it

Comment: Well the problem pretty much has to be in that file. If I include a dummy file with just a `\section{}` command inside it and some text, I don't get a duplicate section in the TOC.

Answer (score 1):

I think table of contents duplicated my third section because I used contour command.This was the command I used.

```
\contour{black}{\section{Monotone Sequences}}
```

It turned out ok when I removed contour

Comment: It is in most cases a bad idea to wrap the `\section` macro in another macro. Further, if you want to style section titles (or parts of it), you should use the optional argument to state the unstyled version of the title, such as: `\section[Monotone Sequence]{\contour{black}{Monotone Sequences}}`.

Comment: Oh that works.I just removed contour entirely.Thanks

Comment: Nice! I only mentioned it, just in case you want to style section titles in the future. Putting macros in section titles often yields unexpected results and using the optional argument for the unstyled version is almost always the solution. The same is true for chapter and subsection titles etc. of course.